# Fading Hyperlink Transition on premiumpixels.com - How?

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

Hover over most any hyperlink on the site (look at the footer on the [homepage](http://www.premiumpixels.com/) for a quick example) and you'll see a gentle fade to the hyperlink's hover color.

I was certain it was jQuery until I could find no mention of these animations in the [jquery.custom.js](http://www.premiumpixels.com/wp-content/themes/premium/js/jquery.custom.js?ver=1.0) file -- only adding specific hover color classes.

Baffled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is doing it:

```
a { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #2c2d31;
font-weight: bold;
transition: color 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
-o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
```

I'm embarrassed to say that I'm unfamiliar with the transition property, but I was baffled at first too, especially after I disabled javascript :)

It worked for me in FF4 and Chrome, but [according to this article](http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/css3-transitions-are-we-there-yet/) I quickly googled, IE9 will not be supporting this property. I wouldn't take that as fact, that's just what I found with 5 minutes research.

Comment: Oh and it goes without saying that this didn't work in IE8 ;)

Comment: How embarrassing. I was so fixated and sure it was jQuery doing it that I didn't take the 3 seconds to see that. Thank you!